# How to fix 'ERROR: Incorrect DATETIME value: %%' in spring data?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I have a page that requests a list of items with a search function.

I just want to point out that this code works perfectly on my work laptop and deployed on my live server but on my home laptop I get the following error:

```
WARN  SQL Error: 1525, SQLState: HY000
ERROR Incorrect DATETIME value: '%%'
```

I use Eclipse EE maven project(spring boot with spring data) with 1.8 java on Windows 10. MySql default dev set-up.
I got the same libraries on both laptops.

Repo call:

```
findAll(request, "%" + f.getSearchField() + "%");
```

Query:

```
@Query( value = "SELECT cl from ConnectionLog cl WHERE cl.user.login LIKE :search OR cl.user.firstName LIKE :search OR cl.user.lastName LIKE :search OR CONCAT( cl.user.lastName,  ' ', cl.user.firstName ) LIKE :search OR CONCAT( cl.user.firstName,  ' ', cl.user.lastName ) LIKE :search OR cl.lastSeen LIKE :search OR cl.browser LIKE :search OR cl.operatingSystem LIKE :search")
    Page<ConnectionLog> findAll(Pageable pageable, @Param("search") String search);
```

The 'lastSeen' field is the DATE column.
Model:

```
@Column(name = "last_seen")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@JsonProperty
@JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_NULL)
private Date lastSeen;
```

How could I make this work? Why would this work on one computer and not on another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question because I found a solution after all. Not sure if it's good but it works...

I've taken out the '%' from the repo call and added to the @Query with CONCAT() and DATE_FORMAT().

```
DATE_FORMAT(cl.lastSeen, '%Y %m') LIKE CONCAT('%', DATE_FORMAT(:search, '%Y %m'), '%')
```

Full Query:

```
@Query( value = "SELECT cl from ConnectionLog cl WHERE cl.user.login LIKE CONCAT('%', :search, '%') OR cl.user.firstName LIKE CONCAT('%', :search, '%') OR cl.user.lastName LIKE CONCAT('%', :search, '%') OR CONCAT( cl.user.lastName,  ' ', cl.user.firstName ) LIKE CONCAT('%', :search, '%') OR CONCAT( cl.user.firstName,  ' ', cl.user.lastName ) LIKE CONCAT('%', :search, '%') OR DATE_FORMAT(cl.lastSeen, '%Y %m') LIKE CONCAT('%', DATE_FORMAT(:search, '%Y %m'), '%') OR cl.browser LIKE CONCAT('%', :search, '%') OR cl.operatingSystem LIKE CONCAT('%', :search, '%')")
    Page<ConnectionLog> findAll(Pageable pageable, @Param("search") String search);
```